# How to change a text not selectable by tag, id or class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change `text to change`. How can do it with jQuery?

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">text to change<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" value="" /></label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not wrap the text in a span tag or close the label tag before the input?

Comment: No, see that inner label content includes more html content!

Comment: @Mahn. This isn't the same question because Nomik's label contains another tag (the input).

Comment: @NomikOS any reason to have the input inside the label tag? afaik most people don't structure it that way.

Comment: @sharethis I can't touch the already existing html! that's why I need do it dynamically.

Comment: @mahn I work over the `wordpress` login form (not editable by me)

Comment: @Mahn - I typically _do_ put my inputs inside their corresponding label elements, mainly because then you don't need the `for="someid"` attribute though also you can then use styles like `label { display : block; }` to put each field on its own line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try then:

```
var newText = 'some text';
$('label[for="user_login"]').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().replaceWith(newText);​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPZus/)

I give no warranties on the performance of this though :) but otherwise it should do.

Comment: @NomikOS I would advise against it to be honest; this is a solution if you absolutely, utterly cannot modify the markup, but otherwise a couple changes would allow faster selectors.

Comment: Of course. In this case I replace the classic `Username` label in the `Wordpress` login form (/wp-login.php) for `Username or Email` (it can't be modified by any WP `hook`). Thanks again.-

Answer (score 3):

```
$("label[for='user_login']").text("New text");
```

See: [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

---

I see, a bit different, something like:

```
var splitElem = "<br>";
var saveHtml = $("label[for='user_login']").html().split(splitElem)[1];
var newText = "New Text"
var newHtml = newText + splitElem + saveHtml;
$("label[for='user_login']").html(newHtml);
```

Comment: this solution replace all inner label content (input included)

Comment: Ah, my bad. I wasn't looking at your label close enough. In a fiddle I made the `<br />` actually turns into a `<br>` by my browser, so you'll need to tune that.

Comment: Yes, I tried a similar solution before came here. The good of your final solution is that can be applied to text in various parts inside `label`. To take in account... THX.-

Answer (score 2):

To replace only the textnode :

```
var newText = 'some text',
    elm = $('label[for="user_login"]').children();
    $('label[for="user_login"]').html(newText).append(elm);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6M8k/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text with a `span` tag.

```
<label for="user_login"><span>text to change<span><br />
<input type="text" name="log" value="" /></label>

$("label[for=user_login] > span").text("replaced text");
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be a good solution because in HTML you can't select and approach text. You are only able to affect the surrounding tags.

There are some possibilities for you now.

- close the label before the input tag and change the content of the hole label
- wrap the text of the label in another tag like a span and affekt the span
- don't change your HTML structure, use JS to get the content of the label and replace the blank text filtered by a regex before
- in JS save the input element, replace the hole content of the label and then append the input element again

Comment: _"You are only able to affect the surrounding tags."_ - That's not true. Once you get a reference to the text node you can change it with [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue).

Comment: @nnnnnn. Didn't know that before. But how to get the reference then?

Comment: Well here's the first one I found with a search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery